# Firebase App Distribution - No "install" button on Google Play window

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-services, firebase-app-distribution

I am deploying an aab with Firebase App Distribution to testers in my company for the first time. Devices not any worries while others ...

Some are blocked on the download window without having any buttons.

[image: App in Google Play window without button]

The problem persists even after clearing the cache and data of the google play services and google play.

The screen is from a Samsung Galaxy S10 with everything updated. The app has been successfully installed on a Samsung Galaxy S8+ (so an older device) and on a Samsung Galaxy A12 (so a most recent device).

An other tester with a Xiaomi mi 11 has the same problem.

Is it a matter of time for all devices to install the app?
What can I do ?

Gradle configurations :

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 8
    versionName "0.105"
}
```

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for getting app bundles be installed? I have the exact same scenario here and don't want to switch to apk.

Comment: Unfortunately, no...

Comment: On my side i discovered that i wasn't logged in with the same account in playstore (i.e. the page which should provide the download link) as with the one i use as firebase tester. When i changed that the download link showed up.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. I switched between all accounts logged in my device within the Play Store app. At a point the "Install" button appeared.

However I still don't understand why it worked while I'm connected with two different accounts on Play Store and App Tester.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem.
This worked for me:

1. Go to Google play store settings clear cache and then clear memory.
2. Go to App Testers settings clear cache and then clear memory and allow installation from unknown source for this app.
3. Login back to the app testers app with allowed tester email.
4. Follow the installation instructions.

Comment: I tried but didn' work. 
It looks like it was an aab related problem. I generated an apk to try and now no one has any problem. I was also having similar issues with the google play console internal test channel. Since then everything has been working perfectly. I don't understand why sharing a bundle is a problem...

Comment: APKS aren't distributed via Playstore when using Firebase App Tester.
However AAB's need Playstore to be distributed, that's why it works for you @Ben
That isn't a solution for the current situatuion.

Comment: I know that’s not the solution. But it’s the only way I’ve found to avoid problems.

Comment: We have the same problem. In your step 2, do you mean clear cache and memory from the App Tester app? Doesnt seem to work in my case.

Comment: I can confirm that I had this exact same issue and that the steps above worked.

Answer (score 4):

**tldr:** This works for me:

1. Go to the Google PlayStore
2. Switch to another Google Account
3. Switch to "App Tester" (by FirebaseAppDistribution) and keep the PlayStore in the background
4. Press "download" button --> PlayStore opens with download button

---

I have reached out to the firebase support team. Their response:

> One reason that this could happen is when you have multiple Play
> accounts registered in your device and have signed in using a
> different Play account than the one you've used when you initially
> downloaded the release of the app.
>
> If so, could you try to switch your Play account and come back to the
> release through App Tester? If you've picked the correct Play account,
> the "Install" button should be visible.

I have told them that everything was working fine for me and suddenly the button disappeared. Hence, I believe this is a bug. Their response was only:

> Per checking, there's an existing feature request regarding this issue
> wherein a message should appear explaining why the "Install" button is
> missing. I’ve raised your case to have it considered as a vote on
> having this kind of feature. There’s no guarantee that would tell when
> this feature will be available, but we'll be sharing your feedback
> within the team which will be included in our internal discussion.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me as well. It's interesting because although I'm signed into multiple accounts, I never use the other one's for google play. The main account is used for everything (even app tester registration).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It is the same case for me!

Comment: Tried your steps, but it doesn't work. I only had one account active on my device and yet I still don't get a download button. I tried adding a second account and going through the steps the support provided to you. Nothing seems to work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and should have noticed it sooner - firebase was logged in with a different email address to the App Store itself.

I think there should be a better user journey than a screen without any buttons on though!